# Automatically change password in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm a Django developer and I want to change the password automatically by system.
This is my python code

```
data = form.cleaned_data
                passw = data["password"]
                print(datax)
                us = User.objects.get(email = datax)
                us.set_password(passw)
                us.save()
```

when I run it, it doesn't save the password.
what can I do?

It doesn't save that new password.

Comment: seems correct to me.

Comment: Could you please format better the question? The code is not indented correctly, there is a print, "datax" is not declared, variable names are unclear. And give more context, like this the question is not understandable.

Answer (score 0):

set_password(raw_password) in docs

Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object.